# while loop keep the browser busy

Tags: javascript

How do I run while loop without browser getting "too busy" ?

I've got this script I need run infinitely:

```
do {
  $("#announcement").css(
    "text-shadow",
    "1px 1px 1px black, 0 0 25px blue, 0 0 5px darkblue"
  );
  setTimeout(function () {
    $("#announcement").css(
      "text-shadow",
      "1px 1px 3px white, 0 0 25px blue, 0 0 5px darkblue"
    );
  }, 1000);
} while (true);
```

But browser gets stuck ... how people use while loops that run within the browser ?

**update:**

With the help of all of you I constructed this:

```
let color = 'black';
$('#announcement').css('text-shadow', '1px 1px 1px black, 0 0 25px blue, 0 0 5px darkblue');

setInterval(() => {
    if (color === 'black') {
         $('#announcement').css('text-shadow', '1px 1px 3px white, 0 0 25px blue, 0 0 5px darkblue');
         color = 'white';
    } else {
         $('#announcement').css('text-shadow', '1px 1px 1px black, 0 0 25px blue, 0 0 5px darkblue');
         color = 'black';
        }
      }, {1000});  // <--
```

Probably not exactly the most elegant solution but this should work. I'm getting `missing : after property id` on marked line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setInterval` instead of loop. Please note, add time in milliseconds in answer as per your need

```
setInterval(() => {
        $('#announcement').css('text-shadow','1px 1px 1px black, 0 0 25px blue, 0 0 5px darkblue');
        setTimeout(function()
        { $('#announcement').css('text-shadow', '1px 1px 3px white, 0 0 25px blue, 0 0 5px darkblue'); },1000);
      },1000)
```

Comment: No need of curly brackets.   Just write 1000 after comma

Comment: Edited my answer. {} indicates values to be placed

Comment: Perfect ! That did it !

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

If you want to toggle between two values every period of time, use `setInterval` and not a loop.

Answer (score 1):

If I got what you want to do, you can do it without javascript, your script have a bad practice since its an infinite loop, if you are looking for [CSS animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) here is how to do it using

```css
#announcement {
  animation: animation 1s alternate infinite
}

@keyframes animation {
  0%, 100% {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black, 0 0 25px blue, 0 0 5px darkblue;
  }

  50% {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px white, 0 0 25px blue, 0 0 5px darkblue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="announcement">Animate this element</div>
```

Comment: I'm gonna try this as well. I like that it uses CSS and nothing else.

Comment: @mr_incredible, yes its simple and out of the box! :)

Comment: People often forget that they can do so so so much with just CSS. So many tricks and transitions. It's not a bad decision to become a CSS master.